# How can I make a class that inherits any one child of a particular base class

Tags: c++, oop

I apologize if this has been answered before but I've been looking for hours.  Here is a contrived example of what I am trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void);

class humanoid {
public:
        int humanoid_attribute;
        virtual void do_something_to_any_humanoid(void) = 0;
};

class man: public humanoid {
public:
        int man_attribute;
        void do_something_to_any_humanoid(void) { cout << "Doing something to a man which is a humanoid.\n"; }
};

class cat {
public:
        int cat_attribute;
        virtual void do_something_to_any_cat(void) = 0;
};

class lion : public cat {
public:
        int lion_attribute;
        void do_something_to_any_cat(void) { cout << "Doing something to a lion which is a cat.\n"; }
};

class sphinx : public humanoid, public cat {
public:
        int sphinx_attribute;
        sphinx(humanoid & humanoidIn, cat & catIn) : humanoid(humanoidIn), cat(catIn) { }
};

int main(void) {
        man myMan;
        lion myLion;

        sphinx mySphinx(myMan, myLion);
        mySphinx.do_something_to_any_humanoid();
}
```

The problem is that when instantiating a sphinx I get the following errors:

```
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.cpp:41:9: error: cannot declare variable ‘mySphinx’ to be of abstract type ‘sphinx’
  sphinx mySphinx(myMan, myLion);
         ^
./main.cpp:31:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘sphinx’:
 class sphinx : public humanoid, public cat {
       ^
./main.cpp:22:15: note:     virtual void cat::do_something_to_any_cat()
  virtual void do_something_to_any_cat(void) = 0;
               ^
./main.cpp:10:15: note:     virtual void humanoid::do_something_to_any_humanoid()
  virtual void do_something_to_any_humanoid(void) = 0;
```

I understand what the error says but can't figure out the proper way to do it.  I do have a valid use for this and yes, 'sphinx' is both some sort of humanoid and some sort of feline and should inherit all their attributes and methods.  Also, the 'man' and 'lion' need to be children so I can make an ugly sphinx.  Can you picture a klingon and a persian?

Comment: child already have parent signature; what do u want?

Comment: you have to provide an implementation for the pure virtual functions `do_something_to_any_cat()` and `do_something_to_any_humanoid()` in the `sphinx` class.

Comment: Note also that you may provide default implementations of `do_something_to_any_cat()` and `do_something_to_any_humanoid()` in `cat` and `humanoid` classes, respectively. With default implementations supplied, `sphinx` needn't necessarily supply its own implemention of these (while still be non-abstract). As long as these base classes have at least one pure virtual function, they will still be abstract and fit their purpose as "interfaces"/pure abstract base classes. This is all under the assumption that default impl. could be a proper alternative for some types derived from the base classes.

Comment: It sounds more like you're thinking of `class ugly_sphinx: public man, public lion`.

Comment: @dfri & Mike :I understand that adding non-virtual implementations in the either the humanoid & cat base classes or in the sphinx class will get rid of the error but I need it to actually call the 'man' version of do_something_to_any_humanoid().  Man's implementation me be very different than a Romulan's.

Comment: @Heath it sounds as if you want to make use of type composition in your `Sphinx` class. I added a somewhat rambling answer including, among other things, this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance expresses the [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship.

If a `sphinx` is both a `humanoid` and a `cat` then the type must be able to be used in all contexts in which a `humanoid` or a `cat` is required. Since these two types have two pure `virtual` methods then you must provide implementations for such methods.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we should look at what you're attempting to achieve: abstract base classes working as interfaces to blueprint methods that objects of non-abstract leaf classes can dispatch.

For this purpose, lets leave the class variables out of it, and focus on an example with only class methods:

```
#include <iostream>

/* astract base classes */
/* -------------------- */
class Humanoid {
public:
  virtual ~Humanoid() = 0;
    // Pure virtual; ensures Humanoid is abstract, even in case we supply
    // default implementations for all "blueprinted" method (not the case
    // for the Humanoid type, but for the Cat type)

  // no default implementation supplied: derived classes
  // must implement this method in order to be non-abstract
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid() = 0;
};
Humanoid::~Humanoid() {}

class Cat {
public:
  virtual ~Cat() = 0; // Pure virtual; ensures Cat is abstract ...

  // supply a default implementation
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyCat() {
    std::cout << "Cat default implementation\n";
  }
};
Cat::~Cat() {}
```

These two base classes are abstract as they have at least one pure virtual method (in the case of `Cat`, only its DTOR).

As a first attempt, we'll try to implement a sphinx class that is common leaf class of `Humanoid` as well as `Cat`:

```
/* non-abstract leaf classes */
/* ------------------------- */
class NotReallyASphinx : public Humanoid, public Cat {
public:
  // by choice (not necessity): use default cat implementation

  // for non-abstractness: implement custom Humanoid implementation
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid() override {
    std::cout << "Needs to be done on four legs ...\n";
  }
};

/* example usage */
int main() {
  NotReallyASphinx notReallyASphinx;
  notReallyASphinx.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(); // Needs to be done on four legs ...
  notReallyASphinx.doSomethingToAnyCat();      // Cat default implementation

  return 0;
}
```

Since `Humanoid` provides no default implementation of `doSomethingToAnyHumanoid`, its a necessity that we implement it in `NotReallyASphinx`, in order for the latter to be non-abstract.

---

Now, for your slightly more sphinx-like attempt at a sphinx, it seems you want to make use of a `Lion` and a `Man` instance (wrapped, however, in addresses of their abstract base classes) to construct the basis for an `UglySphinx`. Lets start by implementing the minimal non-abstract types `Lion` and `Man`:

```
/* non-abstract leaf classes */
/* ------------------------- */
class Man: public Humanoid {
public:
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid() override {
    std::cout << "Doing something to a man which is a humanoid.\n";
  }
};

class Lion : public Cat {
public:
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyCat() override {
    std::cout << "Doing something to a lion which is a cat.\n";
  }
};
```

If you, however, want to construct an `UglySphinx` based on instances of the two types above, you need to resort to *type composition*: where and `UglySphinx` instance in itself owns (responsibility of) instances of `Lion` and `Man`.

```
/* non-abstract leaf classes */
/* ------------------------- */
class UglySphinx : public Humanoid, public Cat {
private:
  Humanoid& m_humanoid;
  Cat& m_cat;
    // we know that humanoidIn and catIn will persist at least
    // as long as the UglySphinx instance, so we'll just work
    // on the stack for this example. An alternative is using
    // pointers here and working on heap; which includes responsibility
    // handling of the heap objects (e.g. owned by UglySphinx)

public:
  UglySphinx(Humanoid& humanoidIn, Cat& catIn) : m_humanoid(humanoidIn), m_cat(catIn) { }

  // by choice (not necessity): use dynamic dispatch to use the
  // m_cat(lion) implementation
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyCat() override {
    m_cat.doSomethingToAnyCat();
  }
  // for non-abstractness: we must implement custom Humanoid implementation,
  // but as above, use m_humanoid(man) for this purpose
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid() override {
    m_humanoid.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid();
  }
};
```

Which would allow us to construct an `UglySphinx` using a `Man` and a `Lion` object:

```
/* example usage */
int main() {
  Man aMan;
  Lion aLion;
  UglySphinx uglySphinx(aMan, aLion);

  uglySphinx.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(); // Doing something to a man which is a humanoid.
  uglySphinx.doSomethingToAnyCat();      // Doing something to a lion which is a cat.

  return 0;
}
```

Since you're intent on working with addresses (alternative pointers) of the abstract base class types, the `UglySphinx` type above would allow us to create an (really) `UglySphinx` instance based on e.g. a `Man` instance and say, a `RagDoll`:

```
/* non-abstract leaf classes */
/* ------------------------- */
class RagDoll : public Cat {
public:
  virtual void doSomethingToAnyCat() override {
    std::cout << "Doing something to a ragdoll which is a cat.\n";
  }
};

/* example usage */
int main() {
  Man aMan;
  RagDoll aRagdoll;
  UglySphinx reallyUglySphinx(aMan, aRagdoll);

  reallyUglySphinx.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(); // Doing something to a man which is a humanoid.
  reallyUglySphinx.doSomethingToAnyCat();      // Doing something to a ragdoll which is a cat.

  return 0;
}
```

---

I can't see the risk of creating ragdoll-based Sphinx being intentional, so perhaps what you really wanted to do was create a `PersistantUglySphinx` which is guaranteed to be composed of `Man` and `Lion` instances (w.r.t. the methods `doSomethingToAnyHumanoid()` and `doSomethingToAnyCat()`, respectively)?

```
/* non-abstract leaf classes */
/* ------------------------- */
class PersistantUglySphinx : public Man, public Lion {
private:
  Man m_man;
  Lion m_lion;

public:
  PersistantUglySphinx(Man& manIn, Lion& lionIn) : m_man(manIn), m_lion(lionIn) { }

  virtual void doSomethingToAnyCat() override {
    m_lion.doSomethingToAnyCat();
  }

  virtual void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid() override {
    m_man.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid();
  }
};
```

Just beware that with this approach we've run into an possibly best-practices issue. Since `PersistantUglySphinx` derives from `Man` and `Lion`, the two latter types are no longer leaf classes, but nor have they been made abstract. Especially when working with "interface"-like inheritance as in this example, I at least personally try to adhere to Scott Meyers advice that we should *"[Make non-leaf classes abstract](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/020163371x/items/item33.html)"* (Item 33 from *"More Effective C++"*).

---

To wrap it up: make sure to understand what an abstract class is, and what is required of a class derived from an abstract class to be non-abstract (i.e., implementations of all pure virtual methods of the abstract base class).

Comment: First - What an amazing reply.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Second - Using type composition seems to be the way to go.  I was just hoping that I didn't have to write all the wrapper methods in the UglySphinx class.  I guess it's a small price to pay for the functionality desired.

Comment: @Heath happy to help! Indeed. Just make sure you think over the functionality you want one extra time, so that you are sure that you're not trying to solve an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Oops.  I'm not used to this web site.

Comment: @Heath ah, I didn't realize this was your first visit to StackOverflow (SO). Welcome! Make sure to read up on the helpful sections [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the site. Also see the meta post [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/), related to the fact that you may choose to (or not, no obligation at all!), accept an answer that you believe answered your question to satisfaction. Happy coding!

Comment: One question about the type composition.  If I do have attributes to the classes and I do it this way, since the m_X variables are references I realize that they won't take any more storage than the already existing objects that are being passed in.  But was about the base classes?  Will storage be allocated for them again when the Sphinx object is created?  If so, is the best idea to create an intermediate class between the base and derived classes that holds the data instead of the base classes themselves?

Comment: @Heath I'm not sure I follow. In this scenario, the base classes (I assume you refer to `Humanoid` and `Cat`) are abstract, in which case they hold no "data" as we cannot create any instances of them. Also, generally focusing on the _size_ of storage needed for a particular application may be pre-mature. Just make sure your _handle_ your stored objects properly: e.g. in case you'd want to use `Humanoid` and `Cat` pointers with related `Man` and `Lion` instances on the heap instead, make sure you delegate the responsibility of deleting these objects to the proper owner (e.g. the `Sphinx` obj.).

Comment: After reading some other posts I've answered my own question about the data / storage.  As far as the XY problem, I'm trying to define a hardware device.  The device has multiple components.  Each of those components can be implemented in multiple ways.  By creating a class hierarchy this way the user end code can treat any of these devices, no matter how implemented, the same way.  I can't go into any further detail at this time.  I'm open to any and all ideas for improvement in any way.

Answer (score 0):

@dfri : My intention is code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void);

class Humanoid {
private:
        int HumanoidAttribute;

public:
        // pure virtual to ensure all derived classes define it
        virtual void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(void) = 0;

        // pure virtual to ensure this is an abstract class
        // not really necessary because doSomethingToAnyHumanoid is pure virtual but good practice
        virtual ~Humanoid() = 0;
};
Humanoid::~Humanoid() { }

class Man: public Humanoid {
private:
        int ManAttribute;
public:
        void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(void) override {
                cout << "Doing something to a Man which is a Humanoid.\n";
        }
};

class Cat {
private:
        int CatAttribute;
public:
        // pure virtual to ensure all derived classes define it
        virtual void doSomethingToAnyCat(void) = 0;

        // pure virtual to ensure this is an abstract class
        // not really necessary because doSomethingToAnyCat is pure virtual but good practice
        virtual ~Cat() = 0;
};
Cat::~Cat() { }

class Lion : public Cat {
private:
        int LionAttribute;
public:
        void doSomethingToAnyCat(void) override {
                cout << "Doing something to a Lion which is a Cat.\n";
        }
};

class Sphinx : public Humanoid, public Cat {
private:
        Humanoid & m_Humanoid;
        Cat & m_Cat;
        int SphinxAttribute;
public:
        Sphinx(Humanoid & HumanoidIn, Cat & CatIn) : m_Humanoid(HumanoidIn), m_Cat(CatIn) { }
        void doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(void) { m_Humanoid.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid(); }
        void doSomethingToAnyCat(void) { m_Cat.doSomethingToAnyCat(); }
};

int main(void) {
        Man myMan;
        Lion myLion;

        Sphinx mySphinx(myMan, myLion);
        mySphinx.doSomethingToAnyHumanoid();
}
```

Since the methods of the base classes are pure virtual I should always notice when compiling the Sphinx class if I'm missing some wrapper methods.

Anyone have any other comments?  I'm new to C++ so any tips are welcome!